# Show that $2^{y-1}|(\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}+...+\alpha_{2^{y-1}-1})$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> **Problem** show that
>
> Let $\alpha_{0},\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},...,\alpha_{2^{y-1}-1}$ are smallest non negative integers such that
>
> $$2^y|(3^{(2^{y-1}+i)}-\alpha_{i})$$
>
> For $0\le i \le 2^{y-1}-1$
>
> Then $$2^{y-1}|(\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}+...+\alpha_{2^{y-1}-1})$$
>
> Where $y$ is given positive integer.

**Example**

Let $y=3 \implies \alpha_{0}=1,\alpha_{1}=3,\alpha_{2}=1,\alpha_{3}=3$

and $2^{y-1}=4|(\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+\alpha_{3})=8$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=2^{y-1}$.
Then $\alpha_i\equiv 3^{m+i}\pmod{2m}$.
Since $\varphi(2m)=m$, we have $3^m\equiv 1\pmod{2m}$.
Consequently:
\begin{align}
s
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\alpha_i\\
&\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}3^{m+i}\\
&\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}3^{i}
\pmod{2m}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
3s
&\equiv\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}3^{i+1}\\
&\equiv s\pmod{2m}
\end{align}
hence $2s\equiv 0\pmod{2m}$ from which $s\equiv 0\pmod m$.